# Displaying data in table format from mysql database with php loop

Tags: php, mysql, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need to display retrieved data from mysql table in table format, but not getting the right display i planned for. This is how i want it to look like
[Target display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVych.png)

But this is what am getting based on my code
[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2y8O.png)

This is the html code

```
<div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php
                    $staff_set = find_all_employee();
                    while ($staff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staff_set)) {
                        //display staff first name, last name, department and action (edit and delete links)
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            echo $staff["first_name"];
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <?php 
                        $staff_set = find_all_employee();
                        while ($staff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staff_set)) {
                            //display staff last name
                    ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            echo $staff["last_name"];
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <?php 
                        $staff_set = find_all_employee();
                        while ($staff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staff_set)) {
                            //display staff department
                    ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            echo $staff["department"];
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="edit_admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Edit</span></a> 
                        &nbsp 
                        <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the function that am using to find the list of all employee from the my staff table

```
function find_all_employee() {
    global $connection;

    $query  = "select * from staff";
    $staff_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($staff_set);
    return $staff_set;
}
```

Is there a better way to write the loop and display my data in the right way? I have looked up similar threads but still not able to grasp.

Comment: Why do you call find_all_employee() function 3 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why you calling so much tie function and also why making so much loops. Let me try fi your code:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
        <?php
            $staff_set = find_all_employee();
            while ($staff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staff_set)) {
                 //display staff first name, last name, department and action (edit and delete links)
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $staff["first_name"]; ?>
                </td>            
                <td>
                    <?php echo $staff["last_name"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $staff["department"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit_admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Edit</span></a> 
                        &nbsp 
                    <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You may also need to edit the code above to include a closing brace for the `while` loop.

Comment: This code snippet could also be improved by performing the DB query before any of the HTML is printed. Simply store the results in an array, and then loop through the array with a `foreach` while inside the HTML table. This would better reflect differing responsibilities of the PHP script and the HTML code, and also allow for easier error handling (in the event that there is a DB error, or no records are found, etc).

Comment: @Standej that fixed it, really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Todd i would love to learn how to do that as well, please tell me how i can achieve same thing by storing the results in an array.

Comment: @Todd I agree I also like it like this more, just i wanted to do less possible changes to code. Also Mena you are welcome!

Comment: @Standej yep I agree, just trying to add some helpful pointers for the OP :)

Comment: @Mena see my answer to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Since OP asked for a varying technique in a comment:

```
<?php 
// Select all staff first name, last name, and department info
$staff_set     = find_all_employee();
$staff_results = array();
while ($staff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staff_set)) {
    $staff_results[] = $staff;
}
?>

<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
        <?php if (!empty($staff_results)): ?>
            <?php foreach($staff_results as $staff_member): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?= $staff_member["first_name"]; ?>
                </td>            
                <td>
                    <?= $staff_member["last_name"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= $staff_member["department"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit_admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Edit</span></a> 
                        &nbsp 
                    <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <tr><td colspan="4">No Staff Members Found.</td></tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This also introduces the [short tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) syntax (`<?=`) for replacing calls to `echo`. Read [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php) if your PHP version is < 5.4. This also introduces [control structure alternate syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), for better readability with HTML. The above approach separates the concern of selecting data from the DB from the presentation of the HTML. This allows for easier debugging, as well as future adaptation and modularization of your application.

Comment: this is very helpful and i will be using it another page am working on and see how it goes.